# Как добавить навигацию по атрибутам товаров в админке?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: Текст]

В админке товаров есть фильтр по категориям, а можно ли как то добавить фильтр по атрибутам?

Comment: см https://wp-kama.ru/id_7524/svoi-filtry-v-tablitsah-zapisej-kommenatriev-polzovatelej.html или используй готовые плагины

Answer (score 0):

Заходишь в левое меню - атрибуты (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q9nh.png)
Далее, выбираешь нужный атрибут - настройка значения (https://i.stack.imgur.com/igT8z.png)
Увидишь список атрибутов и количество товаров (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWgWV.png)
Нажав на него увидишь список товаров с фильтром по атрибуту (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwgq1.png)
Обрати внимание, в адресной строке ты увидишь фильтрацию по атрибуту.
Это если без огорода с плагинами и кастомизаций.

Просто сам подумай, у тебя есть куча разных атрибутов, у атрибутов есть куча значение для фильтрации, понадобиться 2 поля, которые смогут задать комбинацию. А если тебе по 2 или 3 атрибутам, то вообще огород будет. Хотя и реализовать наверно можно.